# Typescript + nodemon + VS Code to work together with declaration merging

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nodemon

I am adding this middleware to my express app

```
app.use(function(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    req.rawBody = 'hello2';
    next();
});
```

And added `custom.d.ts`

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        rawBody: string;
    }
}
```

VS Code shows no error and I can run this command

```
tsc && node --unhandled-rejections=strict ./dist/app.js
```

But I want to use `nodemon` to listen to file changes. So I added this script to `package.json`

```
"dev": "nodemon app.ts",
```

It then started throwing this error

**Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'**

To get rid of the error, I added this to `tsconfig.json` file

```
"files": ["custom.d.ts"],
 "ts-node": {
    "files": true
 }
```

Now nodemon can run fine, but VS Code is showing the same error.

I struggled for hours to get those to work together. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** Currently I am using `tsc-watch` package and it is giving me the desired result.

```
"dev-server": "tsc-watch --noClear -p ./tsconfig.json --onSuccess \"node ./dist/app.js\"",
```

Or if I run these two scripts separately, I get the desired results. The problem with this approach is that whenever there's an error in the code, nodemon doesn't detect that as it is serving the js file. Whereas tsc command detects the error in the code, you can easily miss this until you check the error in the console.

```
{...
"watch": "tsc -w",
"start2": "nodemon ./dist/app.js",
...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `package.json` try this:

```
"dev": "nodemon -T app.ts"
```

`-T` flag will use TypeScript's faster `transpileModule`.

**Update**

`-T` mode won't detect type error but we shouldn't want to skip type error checking. So if we've our custom type path defined inside `tsconfig.json` then the following command will work as desired:

```
"dev": "nodemon --files app.ts"
```

With this command, there won't be any error for our custom type definition but other type error will be raised as desired.

Please make sure to have

```
"paths": {
    "*": [
            "node_modules/*", 
            "path/to/custom/types/*"
         ]
}
```

inside `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: This script is able to listen to code changes, but not able to throw an error in the terminal when there's a type error. Possible to fix this? Currently I am using `tsc-watch` package and it is giving me the desired result.

Comment: there is an update in the answer, can you please check whether it works or not?