# How to start a TypeScript project with a JS library (without type declarations) using nodemon tool?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodemon

I would like to use a JavaScript library (without type declarations) in a TypeScript project.
I created a declaration file for the library. A declaration, for example, is `declare module 'ocsp';`.

It's OK when I run the project with a command "npm run build".
But, there is a problem to start a project by nodemon "nodemon src/index.ts".

It shows the following error:
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'ocsp'. 'D:/Development/Workspace/test-project/node_modules/ocsp/lib/ocsp.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/ocsp` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ocsp';`

How to start a TypeScript project with a JavaScript library (without type declarations) using nodemon tool?

Comment: You should be compiling to JavaScript and then running the JavaScript. Nodemon uses TS-node which unfortunately does not pick up your declaration files or tsconfig by default...

Comment: Why would you want to run TypeScript?

Comment: @youdateme Thank you. The solution is to use -T flag. "nodemon -T src/index.ts" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67756135/typescript-nodemon-vs-code-to-work-together-with-declaration-merging